# update UITableViewCell from other method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have search thousand in GG to find solution update data to UITableViewCell but all show me the solution is

```
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but the cell is nil for all cells that are visible. I have use NSNotification to send data from one method to ViewController.m , and the Reiever method i want update data to cell by indexPath. but all cell is nil and cannt not update that.

here my code 
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
{

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(theReciever:) name:@"theSender" object:nil];

}                
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}       
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"cell nil");

    }

    NSString *idgame=@"Gamexyz";
    cell.textLabel.text = idgame;
    cell.tag=indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}

-(void)theReciever:(NSNotification*)notif{

    if([notif.object isKindOfClass:[packeData class]]){

        packeData *data=[notif object];

        NSString *key=data.key;
        NSInteger *index=[key integerValue];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:index];

        UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

       //UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0]];

        if(cell==nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell NULL");
        }else{
            cell.textLabel.text=data.process;
        }

    }else{
        NSLog(@"ERR: object not recognised");
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

any one can help me or solution example for update data in UITableViewCell by indexPath

Comment: Switch `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Comment: How many section do you have?

Comment: try to reload tableView on 'viewWillAppear' method

Comment: @BlackRider i have change to `UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` but still have cell==nil

Comment: @anhtu did you mean number row i have, if that i have 20 section

Comment: @SahebSingh i have add `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    
}` . still not change, and i want chagne cell of table, not all table

Comment: @SahebRoy my log is  NSLog(@"cell NULL");

Comment: what is the value of `numberOfRowsinTableview` and what is the `indexPath` in your reciever method?

Comment: @TrươngHồngQuyền `Section`, not row. There is a way to get cell with indexPath like this: `NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];`. Maybe `NSInteger *index=[key integerValue];` not get the right index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: below is just an example u can do it in new project

One thing u need to change the data model `packeData`, lets say it contains `key` as `NSIntager` which holdes the index of the cell and `process` is `NSString` which holds the progress as string value for example

in `packeData.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface packeData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger key; //holds index
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *process; //holds the progress info

@end
```

and in `packeData.m`

```
#import "packeData.h"

@implementation packeData
- (id)init //simply initialise it 
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   {

   }
   return self;
}
```

@end

and in view controller where u are tableview,

in `ViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "packeData.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UI TableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>   
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *aTableView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *recipes; //array acts as datasource

@end
```

in in `ViewController.m`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad  
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(theReciever:) name:@"theSender" object:nil];

  _recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //initilise your datasource
  for(int j = 0 ;j< 20;j++)
   {
    // for my example i took some values
    //initially put some initial values
    packeData *data = [[packeData alloc] init];
    data.key = j;
    data.process = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"game_name_%d",j];
    [_recipes addObject:data];
  }
 }

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 target:self selector:@selector(PostNotification) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  //just for testing   
 } 

 - (void)PostNotification
 {
   //i am simply posting the notification with some random values
   packeData *data = [[packeData alloc]init];
   data.key = arc4random()%15;
   data.process = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",( data.key  + 20)];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theSender" object:data];
 }

- (void)theReciever:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    if([notif.object isKindOfClass:[packeData class]]){

      packeData *data=[notif object];
      NSInteger key=data.key;
      NSInteger index= key;
      //modify the datasource
      packeData *recipes_data = [_recipes objectAtIndex:index]; //get the pocket present in array
      recipes_data.process = data.process; //modify the recipes data

      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
      UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[self.aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      if(cell==nil)
      {
         NSLog(@"cell NULL");
      }else
      {
         [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        //  cell.textLabel.text=data.process; no need u already mofied the content in the datasource this will call the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method and displays the process in place of game name
     }
     }else{
       NSLog(@"ERR: object not recognised");
     }
 }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
    return 1;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return [_recipes count];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
   UITableViewCell* cell = [self.aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"cell nil"); 
   }
   packeData *idgame= [_recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = idgame.process; //initially contains game name
   cell.tag=indexPath.row;
   return cell;
 }

 @end
```

**EDIT**

replace the below methods

```
- (void)PostNotification
 {
   //i am simply posting the notification with some random values
   packeData *data = [[packeData alloc]init];
   data.key = arc4random()%15; //15 change the number of rows
   data.process = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",( data.key  + arc4random() % 100)];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]      postNotificationName:@"theSender" object:data];  
 }


 - (void)theReciever:(NSNotification *)notif
 {
    if([notif.object isKindOfClass:[packeData class]]){

    packeData *data=[notif object];
    NSInteger key=data.key;
    NSInteger index= key;
    //modify the datasource
    packeData *recipes_data = [_recipes objectAtIndex:index]; //get the pocket present in array
    recipes_data.process = data.process; //modify the recipes data

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[self.aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell NULL");
        [self.aTableView reloadData]; //if cell is not visible then reload the whole table
    }else
    {
        [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
      //  cell.textLabel.text=data.process; no need u already mofied the content in the datasource this will call the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method and displays the process in place of game name
    }
    }else{
      NSLog(@"ERR: object not recognised");
   }

 }
```

**Edit 2**

as for testing just change the below method and as soon as simulator launches the app scroll to down so that only top 5 rows only updates, wait for 5 to 10 seconds and scroll to top and u will see all the calls are updates with same process 5

```
//scroll down as soon as launches the app and wait for 5 to 10 seconds then scroll to top u will see top 5 cells are updates with progress 5
- (void)PostNotification
{
   packeData *data = [[packeData alloc]init];
   data.key = arc4random()%5; //only top 5 cells are modify other wont modify
   data.process = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",5];//updates with some same progress lates give it as 5 //( data.key  + arc4random() % 100)];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theSender" object:data];
}
```

form the above test u will see the top 5 cells are updates even when they are not visible

Comment: thanks for your solution. but when the cell is scroll and hiden, the textlabel.text will be update. i want update to the cell that are visible in table view. please help me

Comment: that depends on the notification object, it may contains the index of the visible cell or non-visible cell, if the cell is visible that cell progress will be seen or else it won't be appear but update that cell also

Comment: im have try and recheck more and more, the cell is visible and the notification object contain index. but if scroll the table, data will be update, else not

Comment: u mean cell is not updating if the cell is not visible

Comment: I'm very very thrilling for your support. your mean add `[self.aTableView reloadData];` and cell is not visible then reload table. I have edit by your instruction in new project. and it still not working, cell still update after in-visible then visible

Comment: u want to stop updating the cell when cell is not visible ... ? as in edited code, cell is updating even if the cell is not visible .. i don't get what is your requirement

Comment: no, i want update the cell visible and in-visible. but after edit code with suggestion. cell not auto update value and cell not change any thing. it change only if tableview scroll, the cell visible then invisible next visible again will update data

Comment: in my example i am repeatedly posting the notification with random progress values with random index values. In my example a cell is updates with one progress may update again thats depends on random index u can change it to your requirement. i just gave an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89152/discussion-between-shan-and-trng-hng-quyn).

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of any of your cell's controller apart from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have to populate the UITableViewCell data with an array, then when you want to update the data in your cell, update your array according to data, then update the single cell of your UITableView like this.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify your index path of your row and reload...

```
NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path, nil];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```